# How to get good at dynamics

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am a first year engineering student and I am currently struggling with the dynamics prt of my course. It’s not that I don’t understand the theory behind it’s just that every problem I tackle seems to be different from the last one and brings with it different tricks and methods that need to be used. Any advice on how to get good at it?

Comment: Buying books and learning them? I think probably you are interested more like to a different field in it, not in the dynamics in general.

Comment: As you see such introductory engineering material is much about learning how to examine different kinds of problems and think of the appropriate approach to a solution.  You cant get by memorizing procedures . In any case this seems too broad a topic for this forum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in my final year as automotive engineering student, and I have had the same problem, mostly because of the bedrock level teaching quality of my teachers, and because I found my books' explaining vague, abstract, and needlessy complicated.

I resorted to WikiPedia and forums/sites for theory and formula's(still needlessly complicated sometimes), but I benefited most by watching videos. For me, seeing a visual example of the theory in a video, helps me extremely well to understand it. Maybe the same holds true for you.

So i'd recommend following a YouTube channel that explains the theory that you have to know. There are many of them in various languages. You have a lot of teachers uploading courses, and some of them can explain very well. There are also channels that visualise the theory, and I recommend that to get a good grasp of the concept. Theory and practice are inherent to each other.

To be a (good) engineer, you need to know both the theory, and how it works in practice. If you miss one of them, learning will be harder and boring, and you won't understand what you're doing.

Once you start really understanding the theory by visualising it, you'll likely get motivated to learn more about it, and it will also make further learning much easier. Just my $0.02 as a fellow student.